# Fabric.js: Assigning background color to group

Tags: javascript, colors, background, grouping, fabricjs

I am trying to set a background color for a group without affecting its contained objects.

So far my code looks like this:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

var helloText = new fabric.Text('hello', {
  fontSize: 30,
  top: 10, left: 10,
  originX: 0, originY: 0
});

var worldText = new fabric.Text('world!', {
  fontSize: 40,
  top: 50, left: 100,
  originX: 0, originY: 0
});

var group = new fabric.Group([helloText, worldText], {
    selectionBackgroundColor: 'red',
    backgroundColor: 'blue'
});

canvas.add(group);
```

A jsFiddle version can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vzha4gf5/).

As you can see from my code, I already tried the attribute `backgroundColor` yet it only affects contained objects. I would like to achieve an effect similar to  `selectionBackgroundColor`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slight tweak, but this should do it for you (relevant code):

```
var text = new fabric.Group([helloText, worldText], {});
var textBoundingRect = text.getBoundingRect();
var background = new fabric.Rect({
  top: textBoundingRect.top,
  left: textBoundingRect.left,
  width: textBoundingRect.width,
  height: textBoundingRect.height,
  fill: 'blue'
});
var group = new fabric.Group([background, text], {});
```

Your JSFiddle updated, https://jsfiddle.net/rekrah/92ss3d86/.

Comment: Your tweak was my fallback solution ;) Yet, I didn't consider using the bounding rect size to define the background rect's size. Thanks!

Comment: Yep.  I find some of the keywords a little misleading when it comes to FabricJS, I guess you could go both ways with whether `backgroundColor` should refer to the group or to the individual items in the group, I guess.  But I do think that whichever way you go, `selectionBackgroundColor` should be consistent - so since `backgroundColor` refers to individual items in the group, so should `selectionBackgroundColor` - or visa versa.  If you get my drift?  Happy to have helped, matey!